# getOrgChart: different kind of realtionships

Tags: getorgchart

I'm looking for an org chart library and i found getorgchart as a right mix between price and capabilities.
But i'm not totally sure about one important feature.
Is it possible to differentiate staff and line relationship in the org chart using getorgchart?
It seems that its only possible to specity a parent id but not the type of relationship.

Thanks

Comment: What type of relationship you'd like to specify?

Comment: So basically i need to differentiate staff and line relationship. an example of staff relationship is the CEO assistant. Line relationship is an executive position under the  CEO like the CIO. Normally in the org chart these two kinds of relationship are identified by a dot line and a solid line, or by a target point on the left-right for staff and on the top for line relationship.